# why perforce server doesn't ask password on centos?

Tags: centos, perforce

I installed perforce-server on centos 7.
And setted p4 configure set dm.user.noautocreate=2.
and set the password for the user on P4Admin with password security level 1.

after that...
When I connect to perforce, perforce server doesn't ask password...

why? I need more setting to enforce use password?

thanks..

Answer (score 1):

sorry... I checked 'p4 set'
...
P4PASSWD=xxxx
...
so I set 'P4 set PASSWD='

works well(p4 server ask me password)